# minecraft skin uploading problem

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

OK, so I've spent the past 4-5 hours creating and trying to upload my custom skin to Minecraft but it won't work. in version 1.7.5 it works fine, but in the newest 1.10.2 version the skin switches from Steve to Alex. How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure throwing it out the window won't solve any problems.

Comment: Do you mean your skin switches from the Steve *model* to the Alex one (the Alex model has skinnier arms)? Or was your skin the default Steve one, and now it's changed to Alex?

Comment: it switches back and forth from the Steve model and the Alex model

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about models, the answer is simple. When you upload your skin on the website, it asks you what model your skin is based off, like this:[image]
Make sure that the drop down list is set to Steve.

Another reason that it might not be working is that minecraft doesn't recognise the net. I use needcoolshoes.com to make my skins and they work, so if all else fails, try it out!

I hope this answered your question!